# Plot 6-D into 2-D in r

Tags: r, cluster-analysis

How can i plot a data-set with 6 Dimensions in a plot with 2 Dimensions.

I have a dataset with 6 attributes and more than 1000 rows which I am using for k-means clustering.

Now I want to visualise the data after I perform clustering. Could someone give me any hints on how to approach this? Thanks.

Comment: Questions about what is the best type of plot aren't really programming questions. If you want recommendations for statistical visualizations of your data, [stats.se] might be a better place for your question. If you know what plot you want to make but don't know *how* to make it, then that would be a question for Stack Overflow (especially if you include a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example))

Comment: Alternatively, depending on your data, you could get funky in `ggplot2` and map one var to x, one to y, one to size, fill color, border color, shape, ... Or do it in 3D using `rgl`.

Comment: Yes, I know that I need a 2 Dimensional plot but what command I need to use in R is a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest thing would be to use PCA to reduce the dimensionality of your data to 2 or 3 dimensions. k-means clustering ought to assign a group to each row of your data so you can easily plot the different groups on the reduced dataset. Here's a simple way to do PCA though you could also do LLE or other forms of dimensional reduction.

```
data(iris)
unique(iris$Species)
#[1] setosa     versicolor virginica
iris.pca<-princomp(iris[,c("Sepal.Length", "Sepal.Width", "Petal.Width", "Petal.Width")], center=T, scale=T)


plot(iris.pca$scores[,1], iris.pca$scores[,2], col=iris$Species)
```

Comment: with only 6 variables, doing PCA to reduce to 2-3 dimensions might not be necessary ...

Answer (score 1):

`pairs()` might be useful.

Set up data (unstructured, because it's easier to do that way):

```
set.seed(101)
x <- rnorm(6000,nrow=6)
clust <- sample(1:5,size=1000,replace=TRUE)
```

Now plot (`gap=FALSE` is cosmetic; `pch="."` makes the plotting much faster for large data sets):

```
pairs(x,gap=FALSE,col=clust,pch=".")
```

[image]

This only shows you two-dimensional slices (i.e., you might miss higher-dimensional structure in your data this way), but it's better than nothing.  If you really want to visualize higher-dimensional structure you might try something like [rggobi](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rggobi/index.html) ...